# Change the word "Chapter" to something else

Tags: chapters, naming

I am using `fancyhdr`. With that, using the command

```
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Lecture}
```

has no effect. How can I change the name "Chapter" into something else?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

This problem is not due to `fancyhdr`, as the following example shows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Lecture}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}

\end{document}
```

Perhaps you are using `babel` with some idiomatic option? If this is the case, the redefinition needs to be made using `\addto\captions<language>`; for example, in the case of the `english` option for `babel`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Lecture}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 36):

You need to use

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{Lecture}
\makeatother
```

since that's what [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) uses as `\chaptername`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I like that kind of plain LaTeX, avoiding conflicts with other packages

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It worked for me today. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use \renewcommand{\chaptername}{name_you_want} if you put it into the document body.

From this point of document to the end or other redefinition, "name_you_want" will be used to customize your chapter names.

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure whether you are refering to changing the titles of the chapters of changing the page headers. If changing the header, then try changing the following. I have swapped out 'Chapter' for 'Section':

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}}
```

to:

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{Section\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}}
```