# How to remove chapter name with fncychap package

Tags: sectioning, fncychap

I would like to ask you a question. I'm using the `fncychap` package (`Glenn` style) for the chapter titles and I would like to remove the chaptername "Chapter" from each chapter title. Does anyone knows how to do it?

```
\documentclass[11pt,notitlepage,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
\ChNameVar{\bfseries\LARGE\sf}\ChNumVar{\fontsize{62}{65}\selectfont}
\ChTitleVar{\bfseries\LARGE\sf} \ChRuleWidth{1pt} \ChNameAsIs
\ChTitleAsIs

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Because you are using `babel` you need to use `\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand\chaptername{}}`.  See [Change the word Chapter to something else](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30757/2693) which your question is a duplicate of.

Comment: @AlanMunn: at first I also considered this to be a duplicate, but since this particular question admits a different solution (due to the use of `fncychap`) which is not valid in the case of the link that you provided, I am not so sure now whether this is really a duplicate or not.

Comment: @Jane: I edited your original question; basically I changed your original code by removing some packages not relevant to your particular problem, I corrected some typos and loaded some package (`fix-cm`) to have access to a 62pt font. If you don't agree with my edit, you can roll it back; if you can't (due to your actual rep. count), please let me know and I will do it ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, in this particular case, there's a solution which doesn't imply a redefinition of either `\chaptername` or `\@chapapp` and retains their original meaning intact, which can be useful. Due to the way `fncychap` treats the design for the `Glenn` style, all you have to do is to redefine `\FmN` to do nothing:

```
\renewcommand\FmN[1]{}
```

A complete example with the relevant settings from the original question:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}

\ChNameVar{\bfseries\LARGE\sf}\ChNumVar{\fontsize{62}{65}\selectfont}
\ChTitleVar{\bfseries\LARGE\sf} \ChRuleWidth{1pt} \ChNameAsIs
\ChTitleAsIs
\renewcommand\FmN[1]{}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Test Chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I find the Glenn chapter style repellent, but this particular variation makes it even worse. My usual advice about `fncychap` is "don't use it". `;-)` Of course it's a matter of taste and everybody is entitled to have their own.

Comment: @Jane: **egreg** is right in his comment about the Glenn chapter style; the results are particularly poor if a chapter title spans more than one line.

Answer (score 6):

A dirty hack will be to use

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{}
\makeatother
```

in the preamble. This will remove Chapter from title.