# Changing the word "Subsubsection" to something else

Tags: sectioning, naming

I am using babel (spanish) and want to change the name provided by `\subsubsection` (e.g. "Subsubsección" in Spanish) to something shorter (e.g. "Sección")

To that end, I tried to follow the post:

[Change the word "Chapter" to something else](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30757/change-the-word-chapter-to-something-else)

But the command

```
\addto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand{\subsubsectionname}{Sección}}
```

does not work... :(

Any help?

Comment: Please what means "does not work"?  Error message, warning, no changing of the output, ...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. It is really hard to help when we don't know anything about the class you are using or relevant packages!

Comment: Sorry. No error or warning messages, but the output is not changed.  I tried the same with other "titles", e.g. \addto\captionsspanish{\def\listtablename{\'Indice de Tablas}
\def\tablename{Tabla}} and it worked fine...

Comment: Is there anything in the console output or log file which gives a clue?

Comment: The console output (TeXllipse) does not say anything about it... really weird... the question is: is \subsubsectionname the real command, as \chaptername is for chapter?

Answer (score 2):

With `babel` there is no default definition for `\subsubsectionname`; you're probably referring to what `\autoref` does, which requires a different strategy.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\addto\extrasspanish{%
  \def\subsectionname{Secci\'on}%
  \def\subsectionautorefname{Secci\'on}%
  \def\subsubsectionname{Secci\'on}%
  \def\subsubsectionautorefname{Secci\'on}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{A}\label{s:a}
\subsection{B}\label{ss:b}
\subsubsection{C}\label{sss:c}

\autoref{s:a}

\autoref{ss:b}

\autoref{sss:c}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow!!!! Exactly! Now it worked fine. Thanks ! ;)