# Change the name of sections

Tags: sectioning, naming

In the past I just used `\newcommand{\sectionname}[1]{Task~#1}` to make the sections have a different name.
Now it seems to have stopped working.

I am using `babel` with the `ngerman` option.
I have already tried `\addto\captionsngerman` and am now trying with KOMA.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{ucs} % Unicode
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % "utf8x" benutzt "ucs"-Paket, besser als "UTF8"
\usepackage{lmodern} % für Schriftart mit Umlauten
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\renewcommand{\thepart}{\arabic{part}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\alph{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\roman{subsubsection}}

\newcaptionname{ngerman}{\sectionname}{Task~\thesection}
\newcaptionname{ngerman}{\subsectionname}{\thesubsection)}
\newcaptionname{ngerman}{\subsubsectionname}{\thesubsubsection)}

\begin{document}
    \section{}
    \subsection{}
    \subsubsection{}
\end{document}
```

I want the sections to just say "Task 1, Task 2, ...", the subsections "a), b), ..." and the subsubsections to say "i), ii), iii), iv), ...".

I have the feeling I am missing something simple here.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I am not completely familiar with `scrartcl` etc. but I don't think captionname is what you want to change. You have to change the counter output rather

Comment: You may find [this TeX.SX post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30757/55879) useful, though it doesn't directly answer your question.

Comment: There are packages dedicated for exam sheets, like `exsheets`. The fact that you can do `\newcaptionname`  tells you that it isn't defined before, so it isn't used anywhere. If you don't want to use a dedicated package, you could declare a new sectioning command just for the task and subtasks instead of using sections/subsections.

Comment: Going through source code, I can't find anything that uses \sectionname.  The only times it shows up are \let\sectionname=\@empty and \let\sectionname=\appendixname.  You might try \renewcommand{\thesection}{Task~\arabic{section}

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} % für Schriftart mit Umlauten
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\renewcommand{\thepart}{\arabic{part}}
\renewcommand\thesection{Task~\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\alph{subsection})}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\roman{subsection})}

\begin{document}
    \section{}
    \subsection{}
    \subsubsection{}
\end{document}
```