# How to change chapter name to something else without triggering "LaTeX Error: Command \footruleskip already defined" with memoir class?

Tags: sectioning, errors, memoir, chapters

I tried the first and second solution proposed here [Change the word "Chapter" to something else](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30757/change-the-word-chapter-to-something-else) . But once I replaced `book` by `memoir` class. It triggered an error. The first solution was completely broken while the second one, while intact, triggered the following message:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty, line 302
LaTeX Error: Command \footruleskip already defined.
                   Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.302 ...and{\footruleskip}{.3\normalbaselineskip}

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.
```

Here is the code based off the second solution:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{Step}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{How to sow seeds}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `memoir` package emulates a lot of other packages or has built in support for `geometry` and other macros. And it provides its own `page` header/footer commands. Perhaps there's no need to use `fancyhdr` here at all.

Comment: Fancyhdr has nothing to do with the chapter name, and as Christian says memoir has its own pagestyle system so fancyhdr should not be used. You are looking for `\chaptername`, note: if you are using `babel`  as well then the any change to `\chaptername ` should go into `\captions<language>` via `\addto\captions<language>{...}`

Comment: @daleif: I think, you should provide the answer ;-)

Answer (score 2):

First of, since `memoir` has its own build in pagestyle system there is no reason to use `fancyhdr` with `memoir`.

Second the chapter language does not have anything to do with `fancyhdr` or `\@chapapp` for that matter.

The word current word for chapter is stored in `\chaptername`.  `\@chapapp` is a special macro that returns `\chaptername` whenever appendix is not active.

Note: if you're also using `babel` you ought to add your change to `\chaptername` to the `\captionsXXX` macro belonging to the relevant language, for example:

```
\addto\captionsenglish{
   \renewcommand\chaptername{Step} 
}
```

if you are using `babel` with `english`