# Create header with left, center, and right aligned items

Tags: header-footer, memoir, fancyhdr

I have a header on the second page of my document with items aligned to the left, right, and center. Up until now, I have used the fancyhdr package to do the job.

Based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287701/how-to-change-chapter-name-to-something-else-without-triggering-latex-error-co) answer, it seems like the fancyhdr package is redundant when used with the Memoir document class. How can I achieve the same effect without using the package?

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{preamble}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\textbf
{\Large{Christopher M. Finazzo}}
\end{center}
\url{http://www.linkedin.com/in/chrisfinazzo}
\begin{flushleft}
973.906.0496
\end{flushleft}
\begin{flushright}
chris@chrisfinazzo.com
\end{flushright}
\hrule
\begin{center}
\textbf
{COMMUNICATIONS PROFESSIONAL}
\end{center}

\noindent
\begin{raggedright}
Results driven individual with a passion for conveying complex ideas to technical and nontechnical\\ audiences in a way that is accurate, clear, and concise. Proven ability to create audience appropriate messages with a range of authoring tools. Strong verbal and written communication skills as well as the ability to multitask, set priorities, and meet deadlines.
\end{raggedright}
\begin{center}
\textbf{DEMONSTRATED EXPERTISE}
\end{center}
\begin{table}[!th]
\begin{tabular}{lll}
Corporate Communications & Social Media & AP and APA Style \\
Public Relations & Email Production & Adobe Creative Suite \\
Employee Communications & Content Mananagement Systems & Microsoft Office \\
Media Relations & HTML, CSS, and SASS & Final Cut Pro \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{center}
\textbf{PROFESSIONAL EXPERIENCE}
\end{center}
\begin{flushleft}
\textbf{ALLIANT TECHNOLOGIES,} Morristown, NJ \raggedright Nov 2010 - Mar 2011\\
\textbf{AMS Drawbridge Intern}
\end{flushleft}
\begin{itemize}
\tightlist
\item
  Provided end-user support for customers using RSA tokens (Drawbridge 2-factor authentication service).
\item
  Provisioned and managed token inventory for clients, including new
  orders, reassignments, and suspensions. Maintained current token stock
  for future orders.
\item
  Worked with customers to resolve authentication issues, escalating
  support tickets to Senior Engineers/Internal IT Support as necessary.
\item
  Worked with customer contacts (Internal IT) to resolve support
  requests
\item
  Revised documentation and support procedures as necessary to improve
  the process, created procedural workflows (Visio) to show changes over
  time.
\item
  Assisted Tier 1 engineers as necessary to resolve circuit and routing
  issues for customers, escalating issues to Service Providers when
  appropriate.
\end{itemize}
\begin{flushleft}
\textbf{BOROUGH OF CHATHAM,} Chatham, NJ{ Jul 2009 - Sep 2009}\\
\textbf{Intern}
\end{flushleft}
\begin{itemize}
\tightlist
\item
  Created a survey to assess potential renovation options for Memorial
  Pool and gauge community support for the project.
\item
  Worked closely with 3rd-party vendors to develop a new email
  specification for more efficient communication with residents.
\item
  Gathered and compiled updated information for the Borough's Open Space
  \& Recreation Plan.
\item
  Collaborated with other departments to create an updated Policies \&
  Practices manual.
\item
  Updated internal documentation systems, digitized records as needed.
\end{itemize}
\newpage
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{chris@chrisfinazzo}
\chead{\bfseries {Christopher M. Finazzo}}
\lhead{\myphone}
\begin{flushleft}
\textbf{MASS TRANSMIT,} New York, NY{ Jun 2008 - Aug 2008}\\
\textbf{Design \& Production Intern}
\end{flushleft}
\begin{itemize}
\tightlist
\item
  Took HTML email production through static comps, programming,
  validation, testing, and distribution using Email Transmit (Web
  application for email marketing campaigns).
\item
  Integrated WordPress into a redesigned site launch for EGM Green,
  learned basics of server-side programming.
\item
  Developed an early prototype of SEGA Entertainment USA's World Sports
  Grille site using HTML, CSS, and PHP.
\item
  Updated database information for content systems through a custom CMS
  interface as part of a 4RealFoods site launch.
\item
  Created an in-house wiki (MediaWiki) to manage the internal
  technology infrastructure and store client information.
\item
  Learned basics of System Administration (macOS, Linux)
\end{itemize}
\begin{flushleft}
\textbf{RIDER UNIVERSITY,} Lawrenceville, NJ{ Jan 2008 - Jun 2008}\\
\textbf{CIS Technology Lab Monitor}
\end{flushleft}
\begin{itemize}
\tightlist
\item
  Monitored students working in the CIS Technology Lab.
\item
  Troubleshot computer problems
\item
  Assisted students with hardware and software.
\end{itemize}
\begin{flushleft}
\textbf{LEHMAN BROTHERS,} New York, NY{ May 2007 - Aug 2007}\\
\textbf{IT Summer Analyst}
\end{flushleft}
\begin{itemize}
\tightlist
\item
  Coordinated a series of training sessions (Lunch `n' Learn) related to
  firmwide technology initiatives. Managed event scheduling,
  setup/teardown, and provided logistical support during the sessions.
  Created a calendar to manage these events.
\item
  Assisted with production duties related to a Global Technology
  Services town hall meeting. Managed attendance records, event
  setup/teardown, and provided logistical support as needed during the
  meeting.
\item
  Researched employee gift options for a Global Technology Services
  offsite meeting. Collaborated with 3rd-party vendors to evaluate
  sample products and estimate costs. Presented results to management
  for evaluation.
\item
  Drafted a monthly newsletter for the Global Technology Services'
  intranet (IT Portal). Compiled IT Portal feedback reports related to
  content and functionality. Created an archive of past newsletters.
\item
  Worked with technology groups to develop and distribute targeted
  communications related to the availability of systems and testing
  environments.
\end{itemize}
\begin{center}
\textbf{EDUCATION}
\end{center}
Fairleigh Dickinson University, Madison, NJ -- Master of Arts, Class of
2013, Corporate \& Organizational Communication
\linebreak
\noindent
Rider University, Lawrenceville, NJ -- Bachelor of Arts, Class of 2009,
Major -- Communications (Web Design), Double Minor -- Advertising and
Computer Information Systems
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a small but complete document with the code you are currently using for the header. This will make it much easier to help you.

Comment: `fancyhdr` is not redundant, it 'conflicts' with `memoir`  (or `memoir` conflicts with `fancyhdr`)

Comment: Thanks for providing some code, but please provide code in the form of a complete document next time. The above cannot be compiled if I paste it into my editor without my having to guess how to complete it. Not only does this make more work for those trying to help, but it makes helping less likely to be effective because I may not complete it in the same way you would!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer What can `fancyhdr` do that cannot be done (as easily) with Memoir?

Comment: @cfr: I did not say that `fancyhdr` is better or worse. I am no `memoir` afficionado, however

Comment: If there is nothing, then `fancyhdr` is redundant when used with Memoir. Whether you are fond of Memoir or not isn't relevant. Of course, `fancyhdr` isn't redundant *tout court* because it is of great use with standard classes. @ChristianHupfer

Comment: @cfr: As in many occasions, I disagree ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Quoting from the manual "The class also provides functions similar to those provided by the following packages, although the commands are different: `crop, fancyhdr, geometry, sidecap, subfigure, titlesec.` You can use these packages if you wish, or just use the capabilities of the memoir class."  So no conflict, but no real reason to use them either (so redundant).

Comment: @AlanMunn: If I would use `memoir`... yes. You know my opinion about `titlesec` ;-)

Comment: @chris Surely you don't really want (or need) to post your entire CV in your question. A minimal working example is just the bare minimum to show what you are doing. In your case, using `memoir`. The direct content is not relevant (nor useful).  See [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer The point of my comment is that you're spreading false information about `memoir` and `fancyhdr` in your first comment.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that - not intentional.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I'm not sure it is a question of disagreement. Or, rather, I disagree about your factual claim rather than with your opinion. My point was simply a technical one. I wasn't taking any position at all on the relative merits of Memoir or `fancyhdr` or anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that (very nearly absolutely almost) all questions should include a Minimum Working Example (MWE) or Minimal Non-Working Example (MNWE), depending on whether your question concerns how to do something or how to resolve an error. An MWE is code for a minimal but complete document which compiles when copy-pasted into an editor. An MNWE is code for a minimal but complete document which produces the error on attempted compilation after copy-pasting into an editor.

Also, Memoir has an excellent manual and, if you are using this class, there is no substitute for reading the parts relevant to your document. Memoir makes many packages unnecessary - `fancyhdr` is only one of them. It is also necessary to do certain things in your preamble and not do others in order for its layout mechanisms to work correctly. Presumably, you are using it because it produces good-looking output, but it will not do this if you don't follow the instructions carefully.

Of course, if you get stuck, people will be happy to help. But they cannot read the documentation for you.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\makepagestyle{mine}
\makeevenhead{mine}{even left}{even centre}{even right}
\makeoddhead{mine}{odd left}{odd centre}{odd right}
\makeevenfoot{mine}{even left}{even centre}{even right}
\makeoddfoot{mine}{odd left}{odd centre}{odd right}
\checkandfixthelayout
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\kant[1-5]
\thispagestyle{mine}
\kant[6-10]
\end{document}
```

This is page 2 of the document above:

[image: fancy style without <code>fancyhdr</code> for second page]

Comment: I'm probably a little late and sorry for being off-topic, but congratulations on 100k! :)

Comment: @Au101 Thank you. Though I didn't really do anything, so I'm not sure congratulations are in order.

Comment: Thanks all, I'm going to close this out. Up until now, I've been looking at example documents with a reference to ID things and then deconstructing them to figure out how everything works. Using the CV as a starting point exposes many of the common formatting issues that I might run in to, so that's why I chose it. I'm still getting used to the nuances of working with TeX, I really should buy a book and just dive in. Recommendations welcome of course, although I am a bit concerned that most of the references that are suggested are _really_ old. Not sure what to make of it...

Comment: @Chris I recommend Kopka & Daly (whatever the current edition is). At least, I taught myself LaTeX from it more-or-less. The internet certainly existed, but it wouldn't have occurred to me to try to find help there, except in the sense that I downloaded the software, I suppose. I assume there is a newer edition than mine, but the basics you need to start will really have changed very little. Unless the book doesn't cover LaTeX-2e (which would be really ancient), it will not much matter if it is 10 years old or 10 weeks. Bells & whistles have changed, but those come later ;).

Comment: @Chris A series of  free ebooks, starting with: [LaTeX for complete novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/index.html)