# Rename command for Chapter

Tags: table-of-contents, languages

Since, I have not so many days to submit my master report, I need a pratical solution for the following problem. Although in my table of content Bibliography seems so good. However in the Chapter page it is written as German. Maybe problem comes from Babel. I am really in a hurry. Could someone offer me a practical solution both seem as English names.

[image]

Comment: If you would see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30757/change-the-word-chapter-to-something-else that may help you.  I think that this may be a duplicate of that question, although perhaps not, given that there are language issues here.  Some kind of MWE would help.

Comment: It would look like you're loading the `babel` package with the option `ngerman`, or maybe `german`. What happens if you switch the language option to, say, `english`?

Comment: @Mico your solution saved my life :) thanks a lot

Comment: @limonik - Hey, do take care to protect your life!

Comment: You seem to be a  *paint* master.

Comment: @Johannes_B so unnecessary comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Posted just so that this posting can be marked as having been answered.)

From the information you've provided, it looks like you're loading the `babel` package with either the `ngerman` or the `german` language option. I suggest you switch to an option such as `english` -- or `british`, or whichever other language option may be most appropriate.