# When using {book} class, can you hide the "Chapter {num}" line?

Tags: xetex, chapters, books

As you an see below, the following seems kind of redundant. Is there an easy way to get rid of the "Chapter 1" line? Or is this going to require jumping through a bunch of hoops?

[image]

Comment: Try this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30757/change-the-word-chapter-to-something-else

Comment: Just use `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}`.

Comment: or, if you really want no number associated with the chapter, you can use `\chapter*`.  (that way you can mix numbered and unnumbered chapters.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Barnard's comment on my question, provides the answer. Adding the following:

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
```

Produces the following:

[image]