# Table of content Editing

Tags: table-of-contents

This is my first question in the site, I want to make the word "Chapter" all in capital letters and put ":" in front of the chapter title. I used report document class and the only packages for TOC are \usepackage[toc,page] , \usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind} I dont know if they are for modification or not ... i am really just a user in latex and it is my first attempt to write a thesis

```
   \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report} 
   \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amsfonts,mathrsfs} 
   \usepackage{graphicx,epsfig,subfig}                 
   \usepackage{geometry}                               
   \usepackage{setspace}                                 
   \usepackage{array}                                
   \usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}               
   \usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}                  
   \usepackage{xpatch}                              
   \usepackage{fmtcount}                       
   \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\NUMBERstring{chapter}} 
   \renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}  
   \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}  
   \makeatletter
   \input{fc-british.def}
   \xpatchcmd{\@chapter}% <cmd>
   {\numberline{\thechapter}}% <search>
   {\@chapapp~\thechapter\quad}% <replace>
   {}{}% <success><failure>
   \makeatother
   \newcolumntype{L}[1]{>
   {\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
   \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>
  {\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
   \newcolumntype{R}[1]{>
   {\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
    \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
   {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\centering}
   {\centering\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Large}
    \titlespacing*{\chapter}
    {0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
    \geometry{verbose,a4paper,tmargin=30mm,bmargin=25mm,
     lmargin=30mm,rmargin=25mm}
    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.65}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage{psfrag}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
    \usepackage[monochrome]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{pdflscape}
    \usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
    \usepackage{titlesec}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind} 
    \renewcommand\bibname{References}
    \makeatletter
    \newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
    \makeatother
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{5} 
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{5}    
    \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
    \newtheorem{acknowledgement}{Acknowledgement}
    \newtheorem{algorithm}{Algorithm}
    \newtheorem{axiom}{Axiom}
    \newtheorem{case}{Case}
    \newtheorem{claim}{Claim}
    \newtheorem{conclusion}{Conclusion}
    \newtheorem{condition}{Condition}
    \newtheorem{conjecture}{Conjecture}
    \newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
    \newtheorem{criterion}{Criterion}
    \newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
    \newtheorem{example}{Example}
    \newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}
    \newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
    \newtheorem{notation}{Notation}
    \newtheorem{problem}{Problem}
    \newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
    \newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
    \newtheorem{solution}{Solution}
    \newtheorem{summary}{Summary}
    \numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
    \numberwithin{theorem}{chapter}
    \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields 
    \fancyfoot[C]{\bfseries\large\thepage} % except the center
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}

    \begin{document}

    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
    \tableofcontents 

    \chapter{General Introduction}\label{chapter:Intro} 
    \section{Introduction}
    Composite steel-concrete construction

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please add some working code. Related [Change the word “Chapter” to something else](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30757/124842)

Comment: We really need to know which document class you use, and also if you load any package that help modify the appearance of the table of contents. Some of these packages are not mutually compatible; that's why it's important which packages (if any) you are already loading.

Comment: I used report document class and the only packages for TOC  are \usepackage[toc,page] , \usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind} I dont know if they are for modification or not  ... i am really  just a user in latex and it is my first attempt to write a thesis

Comment: The way this site works, one typically add a Minimal Working Example (NOT the entire document) which shows the problem, or at least what you are doing now.  We play with the code until it does what you want.

Comment: That's a pretty maximal minimal example, isn't it?

Comment: Use `\setstretch{}` and don't change `\baselinestretch`. Or don't load `setspace`, as there's no point otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started by reducing your code to a more minimal working example. Although you obviously don't want to do that in your real document, you **should** prune and organise your preamble. You are loading packages multiple times, sometimes with different options, and loading conflicting packages or packages which conflict with options passed to other packages. For example, `pagestyles` passed to `titlesec` will load that package's footer/header cousin. That cousin will then compete with `fancyhdr` for control of that aspect of your document layout. Pick. One, other or neither. But not both. You also load `titlesec` without this option, which creates potential conflicts, too, if you don't happen to happen upon an order which doesn't trigger an error.

I then adjusted the `\xpatch` command to set 'Chapter' as 'CHAPTER' and to put a stop after the number word. I know you requested a colon, but I frankly think that looks weird. However, you can easily replace the `.` by a `:` if you really prefer (or are required to use) this format.

```
\documentclass{report} 
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}               
\usepackage{xpatch}                              
\usepackage[british]{fmtcount}% set dialect in a standard way the package recommends                
% \usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}% use of pagestyles conflicts with use of fancyhdr
\usepackage{titlesec}% use of pagestyles conflicts with use of fancyhdr
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind} 

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\NUMBERstring{chapter}} 
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}  
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@chapter}% <cmd>
{\numberline{\thechapter}}% <search>
{\MakeUppercase{\@chapapp}~\thechapter.\quad}% <replace>% <= \MakeUppercase for the capitalisation; added . for dot
{}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\centering}
{\centering\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Large}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}    
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}% clear all header and footer fields 
  \fancyfoot[C]{\bfseries\large\thepage}% except the center
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}

\begin{document}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
\tableofcontents 

\chapter{General Introduction}\label{chapter:Intro} 
\section{Introduction}
Composite steel-concrete construction

\end{document}
```

[image: tweaked ToC line for chapter]