# How can I create a better worksheet for my students?

Tags: formatting

I am trying to create a worksheet for my students (the text in there is not the real one, just written to give the reader an overview of the structure). Unfortunately, my skills with this program are very limited ... and I would like to create a worksheet that I can apply universally. Basically, just change the tasks but I don't want to re-create it every single time. That's why I thought it is best to use LaTeX. But now there are so many hurdles coming up with this program.

- I would really like to keep the font (similar to Arial, it somehow disappeared in the photo).
- However, a problem is that "Class:, Teacher:, Date:, Name: are on a separate page. And are not nicely aligned but I don't know how to solve this issue.
- I would "Chapter 1" to be called "Teil 1" but I don't know how to rename \chapters, \sections, etc. on LaTeX
- The lines need to be further apart, for handwriting

The picture below

[image: Present "progress"]

I would appreciate any help! Thank you

```
\documentclass[
    egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles,
    headings=optiontoheadandtoc,
    chapterprefix=true
    ]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{csquotes}


\usepackage{newtxtext}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\LARGE}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\normalfont \itshape}

\usepackage{tikz} %circle
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc,shadows}
\begin{document}

  \begin{center}Class: Name \end{center}
   \begin{center}Teacher: Name \end{center}
\begin{center} Date: \line(1,0){100} \end{center} 
  \begin{center}Name: \line(1,0){275} \end{center}
\chapter{Facts on London}
\section{ London past and present}
\subsection*{An extract of a tour guide}
\textbf{London: Discover the city ...} \quad\\
\quad\\\quad\\
EXTRACT/TEXT ABOUT LONDON \quad\\\quad\\
\vspace{0.5cm}
Notes: \quad\\  %Student notes - lines need to be further apart
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
\pagebreak
\chapter{Culture}
\section{The word \enquote{culture}}
\vspace{2.5cm}
\centerline{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(char.base)]
\node(char)[draw,fill=white,
  shape=rounded rectangle,
  drop shadow={opacity=.5,shadow xshift=0pt},
  minimum width=1.8cm]
{\Large Culture};   %puts a circle around the word /mind-map
\end{tikzpicture}
}   
\vspace{2.5cm}


\section{Extracts of a tour guide}
Exercise: Read the extract and discuss it with your partner in your target language. Summarize the key facts. \quad\\\quad\\
\vspace{0.5cm}
Notes: \quad\\
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}

\section{If-Clause}
Exercise: What would you do if you were in Berlin? \quad\\\quad\\
Text: \quad\\
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}

\section{Homework}
Exercise: Write a short extract (tour guide style) on a cultural aspect of your hometown.


\end{document}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30757/change-the-word-chapter-to-something-else) in order to rename the chapters. In addition, I feel like there are much simpler ways of creating "fillable" documents, but it's not my domain of expertise... yet.

Comment: thanks, will definitely apply this!

Comment: The eforms package creates text fields which can be edited by most PDF viewers (assuming you want them typed instead of hand written).

Comment: What I rather thought about -- but unable to do -- is to create one document with a standard code that gives you a structure. The other document would include the individualized tasks that would adapt to that structure. Is there a possibility to do that?

Comment: In terms of using common structure for many documents, you basically need to define a bunch of macros to handle everything but the names.  The first step is to get a form you like.  Then you can turn it into a macro.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Do you have an idea where to find information on that specifically for worksheets?

Comment: Not really, but I do have some experience in that area (http://www.elfsoft2000.com/worksheets/index.htm).

Comment: I just did a bit of digging. I think I'd have to define environments. It just seems really difficult. I just cannot find an introduction page on worksheets that work with "environments".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107829/discussion-between-john-kormylo-and-karl-l).

Answer (score 1):

If your class would rather use laptops than pencils, you can use the following PDF.  Note that each field must have a unique id.

Not sure what all the `\quad`s were for, except as one way to `\leavevmode`.  Note that `\\[2\baselineskip]` will add 2 blank lines.

`\arraystretch` and `\normalbaselineskip` apply only to tabulars.

```
\documentclass[
    egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles,
    headings=optiontoheadandtoc
    ]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{newtxtext}
\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\normalfont \itshape}

\usepackage{tikz} %circle
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc,shadows}

%\usepackage{showframe}% alaignment tool, remove
\usepackage{eforms}% should come last

\begin{document}


\begin{center}
  \def\arraystretch{1.5}% increase spacing between lines, local to environment
  \begin{tabular}{rl}
    Class: & \textField[\inline{y}]{class}{1in}{\normalbaselineskip}\\
    Teacher: & \textField[\inline{y}]{teacher}{1in}{\normalbaselineskip}\\
    Date: & \textField[\inline{y}]{date}{1in}{\normalbaselineskip}\\
    Name: & \textField[\inline{y}]{student}{1in}{\normalbaselineskip}
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\section{Facts on London}
\subsection{ London past and present}
\subsubsection*{An extract of a tour guide}
\textbf{London: Discover the city ...}
\bigskip
EXTRACT/TEXT ABOUT LONDON\par
\vspace{0.5cm}
\noindent Notes\strut\\
\textField[\Ff\FfMultiline]{london}{\textwidth}{6\baselineskip}

\pagebreak
\section{Culture}
\subsection{The word \enquote{culture}}
\vfill% expand to fill available space
\centerline{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(char.base)]
\node(char)[draw,fill=white,
  shape=rounded rectangle,
  drop shadow={opacity=.5,shadow xshift=0pt},
  minimum width=1.8cm]
{\Large Culture};   %puts a circle around the word /mind-map
\end{tikzpicture}
}   
\vfill

\subsection{Extracts of a tour guide}
Exercise: Read the extract and discuss it with your partner in your target language. Summarize the key facts.

\vspace{0.5cm}
\noindent Notes: \strut\\
\textField[\Ff\FfMultiline]{guide}{\textwidth}{5\baselineskip}

\subsection{If-Clause}
Exercise: What would you do if you were in Berlin? \\[2\baselineskip]
Text: \strut\\
\textField[\Ff\FfMultiline]{berlin}{\textwidth}{5\baselineskip}

\subsection{Homework}
Exercise: Write a short extract (tour guide style) on a cultural aspect of your hometown.

\end{document}
```