# Rename chapter by word Lecture by Koma-script

Tags: koma-script

Is there simple way how to obtain customization of the chapter for scrbook? I want to have

**Lecture 1. My first lecture**

I try to do:

```
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Lecture}
```

but nothing happen. I try to ready [scrguien](http://ftp.fau.de/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf) and also the similar question ["Change the word "Chapter" to something else"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30757/change-the-word-chapter-to-something-else). I hope that, this not need to load other packages like `fancyhdr`.

My MNWE is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Lecture}

\begin{document}
  \chapter{My first lecture}
  \blindtext[1]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not want a second line for the chapter title you can redefine `\chapterformat` and maybe `\chaptermarkformat`.

```latex
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\chaptername~\thechapter\autodot\enskip}
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{\chaptername~\thechapter\autodot\enskip}
```

If there should be a dot after the chapter even if option `numbers=noenndot` or `numbers=autodot` (default) is used:

```latex
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\chaptername~\thechapter.\enskip}
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{\chaptername~\thechapter.\enskip}
```

To rename the chapter prefix you can use

```latex
\defcaptionname{english}{\chaptername}{Lecture}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[
  numbers=enddot
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}

\defcaptionname{english}{\chaptername}{Lecture}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\chaptername~\thechapter\autodot\enskip}
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{\chaptername~\thechapter\autodot\enskip}

\begin{document}
\chapter{My first lecture}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Try this code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,chapterprefix=on]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Lecture}% change Chapter for Lecture

\begin{document}
    \chapter{My first lecture}
    \blindtext[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: a]

`chapterprefix=on` makes “Chapter” to appear before the chapter number.

Comment: Now that's a proper magic formula: chapterprefix=on. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

Same output of very nice use @Simon Dispa (+1) using `chapterprefix=true` (you can see the guide to pag. 61 to the link https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf)

[image]

There is the same effect instead of `chapterprefix=on`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Lecture}

\begin{document}
  \chapter{My first lecture}
  \blindtext[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank for your support! :) `true` sounds better and definitive while `on` looks reversible (and is shorter).

Comment: @SimonDispa :-))))))))))